# How to use html textarea compnent in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, html

I am having a field, `Final_Step__c` which is of data type Text Area.

I am showing it in VF page:

but, due to maximum length issue of `<apex:textarea>` i wanted to use html `<textarea>` component with `maxlength` attribute.

so, any idea how to use `<textarea>` component in VF page?

Comment: are you referring to apex:inputTextArea?  I don't know of an apex:textarea component per the VF doc.

Comment: <textarea> is a HTML component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VF component `apex:inputTextArea` generates `textArea` as underlying HTML. To support the maxlength attribute, you use HTML-5 pass-through attributes as documented [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm?SearchType=Stem).

Here is a simple example (no controller extension required):

```
<apex:page standardController="Foo__c" doctype="html-5.0">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
   <apex:inputTextArea value="{!Foo__c.bar__c}" html-maxlength="10" rows="2" cols="10"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The above assumes field `bar__c` is of type textArea as per your problem statement

Notes

1. `apex:page` requires adding attribute `doctype="html-5.0"`
2. You 'pass through' the VF attribute `html-maxlength` to the underlying textarea HTML-5 `maxlength` attribute